# Sphinx toctree directive: How to hide the caption from being displayed?

Tags: python-sphinx, caption, toctree

If I have the following in `index.rst`:

```
This Section
------------

.. toctree::
   :caption: This Section
   :maxdepth: 1

   this_section/intro
   this_section/body
   this_section/outro
```

Then "This Section" would show up twice in the generated HTML file: One as a `<h1>`, one as a `<p class="caption">`. How can I get rid of the latter, or make `:caption:` generate a `<h1>`? I can't simply remove `:caption:` because the sidebar (I'm using ReadTheDoc theme) relies on this option to correctly generate a TOC tree.

Comment: Did you find a satisfactory solution/workaround to this?

Answer (score 2):

My workaround is to hide the original toctree and link again to contents...

```
This section
------------

* :doc:`intro <this_section/intro>`
* :doc:`body <this_section/body>`

.. toctree::
   :caption: This Section
   :hidden:

   this_section/intro
   this_section/body
   this_section/outro
```

Comment: both answers work well, but I believe this one should be the accepted one

Answer (score 2):

I ended up removing this with css by adding this to `custom.css` in the `_static` directory:

```css
section#setup span.caption-text {
    display: none;
}
```

And having this in my `conf.py`:

```py
html_static_path = ['_static']
html_css_files = ['custom.css']
```